# Would stronger tendons and bones allow for stronger muscles for the same weight?

Tags: science-based, bio-mechanics

Follow-up to this question:

[Would linear increase of a muscle's dimension increase the power as well?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/157610/32097)

Let's suppose there is a genetically engineered creature that has the abilty to synthesize graphene and use it in its tissues.

This would allow for stronger bones and tendons for the same weight. It is know that muscles could be theoretically made strong enough that they rip themselves off the bone or outright break it in two.

So, would stronger tendons and bones allow for significantly stronger muscles as well?

Comment: Muscles can be made strong enough that they rip themselves up or break bones in reality, there's nothing theoretical about it.

Comment: @AlexP Tell me more, please. This sounds gud.

Comment: [Biceps tendon rupture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biceps_tendon_rupture). [Avulsion fracture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avulsion_fracture). Muscular [strain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_(injury)) (aka "pulling a muscle"). An [introduction to muscle injuries](https://www.hss.edu/conditions_muscle-injuries-overview.asp). See also the symptoms of [tetanus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetanus).

Comment: In addition to AlexP's comment re tendon rupture, stronger bones, even for a relatively same sized person or creature, can allow for [stronger muscles](https://www.livescience.com/21682-neanderthals-arm-strength.html).  It's a matter of normal personality, self awareness & control of strength that ordinarily prevents us from tearing muscles and breaking bones on a whim.

Answer (score 2):

To an extent. But not as much as you're thinking. Because part of muscle injuries are [muscle strains](https://www.health.harvard.edu/a_to_z/muscle-strain-a-to-z), or muscles tearing through themselves. So if you increased the strength of bone and tendons so that muscles couldn't hurt them, then the muscles would be set back on themselves. And if you increased the strength of muscles (here I'm assuming that you're increasing the pulling capacity of the muscle) so that you had to worry about ripping the muscles of the bones, then you also have to worry about ripping the muscles themselves.

*So just put graphene in the muscle!* is the natural response. Well, then your muscles wouldn't work. Graphene is many things, but flexible and elastic isn't one of them. You can't lace a muscle with graphene and expect it to work like you can a bone, because then the muscle is essentially petrified and cannot contract.